# Accessing relation data in an on save entry event

Tags: plugin-development, entries, relations

I have a front end form that saves an entry with a relation field based on an ID.

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ index }}][finish]" value="{{ finish.id }}">
```

When the entry is saved this ID saves the field with the correct category relation.

I then have a plugin which triggers on entry save that sends an email and attaches the `$entry`.

```
craft()->on( 'entries.saveEntry', function( Event $event ){
    $entry = $event->params['entry'];
    if( !$event->params['isNewEntry'] || $entry->section->handle != 'sampleOrders' )
    {
        return;
    }
    //die(Craft::dump($entry->samplesOrder[0]->finish->find()));
    $email = new EmailModel();
    $email->toEmail = 'luke@ten4design.co.uk';
    $email->subject = 'Order Received';
    $email->body = '';
    $email->htmlBody = craft()->templates->render( 'pentagonemailservice/_emails/order', array(
        'entry' => $entry
    ) );
    try{
        craft()->email->sendEmail( $email );
    }
    catch( Exception $e ){
        Craft::log( 'Could not send email.', LogLevel::Error );
    }
} );
```

For some reason in my email template I cannot access the finish field with the following code. The other fields print correctly. The finish field is a category relation.

```
{% for item in entry.samplesOrder %}
    {% set appr = craft.entries.section( 'appearances' ).apprId( item.appearance ).first() %}

    <h3 class="appearance__name h beta"><a class="a" href="{{ appr.url }}">{{ appr.apprId }} - {{ appr.displayName }} - {{ appr.pentagonRange[0].title }}</a></h3>

    <h3 class="h h6 caps--spaced m-b--05">Material</h3>
    <p class="appearance__material h delta basket-bits">{{ appr.material }}</p>

    <h3 class="h h6 caps--spaced m-b--05">Finish</h3>
    {#<p class="basket-bits">{{ finish.title }}</p>#}

    <h3 class="h h6 caps--spaced m-b--05">Quantity</h3>
    <p class="basket-bits">{{ item.quantity }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I access the finish field in my email template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related elements, such as categories, are stored by Craft as arrays, even if there is only a single element to be stored.

In your entry form, you don't appear to be storing an array, but only the id of the selected category:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ index }}][finish]" value="{{ finish.id }}">
```

This seems to be borne out by what you see when you dump the `item` variable in your email template. `item[finish]` should be an array, even if only a single category is assigned to it.

Try using the following in your entry form to see if that helps, which should store the category id as an array:

```
<input type="hidden" name="items[{{ index }}][finish][]" value="{{ finish.id }}">
```

You should then be able to access the correct value for the category title using the code in [@carlcs answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/12806/153).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has something to do with your event listener, and you just access the related elements not quite right. Try to get them like so:

```
{% set finish = item.finish.first() %}
{% if finish %}
    <h3 class="h h6 caps--spaced m-b--05">Finish</h3>
    <p class="basket-bits">{{ finish.title }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

or use a `relatedTo` query to get the finishes form the field.

Comment: Using `{{ entry.finish.first().title }}` gave me:

`Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a null variable`

Tried using `{{ item.finish }}` and it gives me the following:

`Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string`

But using `{{ item.finish[0] }}` gives me

`Key "0" in object with ArrayAccess of class "Craft\ElementCriteriaModel" does not exist`

Comment: Yep, sorry. It's the `item` variable, not `entry`. Updated the answer.

Comment: `item.finish.first()` returns NULL.

Comment: If I dump `item` I can see the following : `["samplesOrder"]=> array(1) { ["new1"]=> array(3) { ["type"]=> string(5) "order" ["enabled"]=> string(1) "1" ["fields"]=> array(3) { ["appearance"]=> string(7) "SAN0004" ["finish"]=> string(3) "514" ["quantity"]=> string(1) "1" } }}}`